# react-konva - running sprite animation and filter at the same time

Tags: reactjs, konvajs, react-konva, konva

To summarize, I can't animate Konva sprites and apply Konva filters at the same time.

I'm drawing a complex stage using react-konva, and parts of it contains animated images using Sprite component animations. In order to start the animations, I am waiting until the nodes are drawn in the browser, with a bit of a "hack" (setTimeout), and then calling shape.start() on each one to start them.

```
    initiateAnimations = () => {
       setTimeout(() => {
           let stage = this.stageRef.getStage();  
           var shapes = stage.find('.canvas-animation');
           shapes.map(shape => {
               shape.start();
           })
       },100)      
   }
```

I also add a color overlay to these images, depending on properties that I feed into the Sprite components before render. I use the Konva RGBA filter for this - it's not perfect but kind of gets the job done. In order to initiate and draw the filter, Konva needs the images to be re-cached, and so after the nodes are drawn in render(), I use the cache and batchDraw functions for this.

```
   applyEffects = () => {
       setTimeout(() => {
           let stage = this.stageRef.getStage();
           var shapes = stage.find(node => { return node.attrs.id.includes("-f1") ? true : false; });
           shapes.map(shape => {
               this.applyCache(shape)
           })
       },100)      
   }

   applyCache(target) {
       target.cache();
       target.getLayer().batchDraw();
   }
```

I have all of this both in componentDidMount and componentDidUpdate.

The problem I am encountering is that the animations and filters work on their own, but *never together*, regardless of time delays or which order they are in. In conjunction, only the filter will work. On the other hand, if I run only the animation script, the animations start and run fine. But together, the animation just doesn't start. I think I just don't understand the lifecycle here well enough, but maybe someone can help point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the current moment `konva@7.0.3` doesn't support caching/filters for `Sprite` object.

As a workaround you can:

1. Create `Konva.Image` instance with the image of sprite and use filters on it.
2. Use `node.toImage()` method to convert `Konva.Image` instance into a native image element. As a result you will have and sprite image but with filters applied
3. Use resulted native image for the animated sprite